# Are the contents of os/x86_64/ on public mirrors the same as those of CentOS ISOs?

Tags: linux, centos, mirror

When I mount a CentOS 7.2 ISO in `/mnt/centos7/`, then list its contents, I get:

[image]

(I can not copy, I only can take a screenshot.)

Now I enter a CentOS public mirror repo detail directory:
http://mirror.scalabledns.com/centos/7.7.1908/os/x86_64/

and find they are largely identical but with minor differences (in `/mnt/centos7/` there is an extra `TRANS.TBL`).

1. On the public mirror, is `os/x86_64/` the same as the contents of the CentOS ISO?
2. What's the function of the contents? Do they provide the repo function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Strictly speaking, it’s the other way round: the CentOS CD images provide a snapshot of (a subset of) the online repositories.
2. The contents do indeed provide a local repository, from which packages are installed without needing access to the online mirrors.

Incidentally, `TRANS.TBL` is only present on CDs because it’s [used to encode file system information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRANS.TBL) which can’t be represented using the basic [ISO 9660 CD file system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_9660).

Comment: and the CentOS CD image content is as same as the public mirror's `os/x86_64` content, alright?

Comment: The content of the CentOS CD image is the same as the public mirror's *was* at the time that particular minor release was released. If the repository receives updates, it might include updated versions of packages that have received bugfixes since the day of the release. A CD obviously cannot have those.

Comment: I agree with this.

Comment: Yes, that’s what I meant by “snapshot”.